# Adding a user (useradd) via PHP - Ubuntu

Tags: php, shell, ubuntu, system

I am trying to add a user to the server in a PHP script, however it's not working.

Here is my code:

```
$user = $_GET['user'];

system("sudo useradd -m -p 4dk/kBWvKaP52/POJYOZGLam8qZnCkQtdw== $user; echo $user");
```

Yes, I know how dangerous this is.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `setuid` bit on the script file and `chown` it to root so it runs as root, e.g. `chmod u+s file.php`.